# How to select last row for specific user?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// requests
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | id_user  |  unix_time  |
+----+----------+-------------+
| 1  | 2353     | 1339412843  |
| 2  | 2353     | 1339412864  |
| 3  | 5462     | 1339412894  |
| 4  | 3422     | 1339412899  |
| 5  | 3422     | 1339412906  |
| 6  | 2353     | 1339412906  |
| 7  | 7785     | 1339412951  |
| 8  | 2353     | 1339413640  |
| 9  | 5462     | 1339413621  |
| 10 | 5462     | 1339414490  |
| 11 | 2353     | 1339414923  |
| 12 | 2353     | 1339419901  |
| 13 | 8007     | 1339424860  |
| 14 | 7785     | 1339424822  |
| 15 | 2353     | 1339424902  |
| 16 | 2353     | 1466272801  |
| 17 | 2353     | 1466272805  |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

I'm trying to get last row which is related to specific user. For example for this user `id_user = 7785` I want to select this row:

```
| 14 | 7785     | 1339424822  |
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT unix_time AS last_seen
FROM requests WHERE id = '7785'
ORDER BY unix_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

But my query doesn't select any row. What's wrong?

### [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad035/17)

---

Also as a note, can you please tell me should I create single index on `id_user` and `uinx_time` or should I create a multiple columns index on those two columns `(id_user, unix_time)`?

Comment: you have put where id = 7785 instead of where id_user = 7785

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let a sub-query return each id_user with it's highest unix_time. Join with that result.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join (select id_user, max(unix_time) as unix_time
        from tablename
        group by id_user) t2
     on t1.id_user = t2.id_user and t1.unix_time = t2.unix_time
```

Will return all users and their latest login.

Add `WHERE id_user = '7785'` if info about a single user is wanted.

Comment: Yes your query would be fine. But I think I can do that without a join. thx anyway

Comment: Ah ok, thank you for the edit, upvote ..! Just may you please tell me what kind of index do I need in this case? a multiple column index on `(id_user, unix_time)` or two separated index on those two columns?

Comment: @stack, I'm not a MySQL guy, but I suppose a combined index (id_user, unix_time) would do the trick.

Comment: Two downvotes in 1 minute, on different answers, without any explanation... At least give me an explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You are using the wrong column (`id` instead of `id_user` — or vice versa):

```
SELECT unix_time AS last_seen
FROM requests WHERE id_user = '7785'
ORDER BY unix_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Oh good eyes, upvote ... thx ... Also here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad035/33

Comment: Just may you please tell me what kind of index do I need in this case? a multiple column index on `(id_user, unix_time)` or two separated index on those two columns?

Comment: @stack you need a multi-column index as you said `(id_user, unix_time)`. This is described on my website too: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/top-n-queries

Answer (score 1):

In the WHERE condition you are comparing id with id of id_user.
Your mistake is at line two, it should be like:

```
SELECT unix_time AS last_seen
FROM requests WHERE id_user = '7785'
ORDER BY unix_time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Correct *(as @Markus Winand mentined)* .. thank you, upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You have:
WHERE id = '7785'

If you want the row: | 7  | 7785     | 1339412951  |

You need something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 unix_time AS last_seen
FROM requests WHERE id_user = '7785'
ORDER BY unix_time DESC
```

This will take the top result of the query where the user_ID equals '7785'. The 'ORDER BY unix_time DESC' puts the values with the highest unit time at the top so it will by the last request that user has had.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query it will help you

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(id,',',1) AS id ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(id_user,',',1) AS id_user, unix_time FROM 
 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY unix_time DESC )  AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(id_user ORDER BY unix_time DESC  ) AS id_user ,MAX(unix_time)  AS unix_time FROM test_71 GROUP BY id_user
  HAVING id_user='7785' ) t   ;
```

Comment: This query is over complicated while we can get expected result much simpler. Please take a look at other answers.